# catchError of sample "https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6" it's not working

Tags: angular, typescript, phpstorm, angular7

If you copy the class of hero.service.ts exposed on the Angular's docs page, you're going to see a problem on the call to `catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))`.

The error is:

[image]

Follow the complete typescript class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService) { }

    /** PUT: update the hero on the server */
      updateHero (hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
          tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
        );
      }
    /**
       * Handle Http operation that failed.
       * Let the app continue.
       * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
       * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
       */
      private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

          // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
          console.error(error); // log to console instead

          // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
          this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

          // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
          return of(result as T);
        };
      }

      /** Log a HeroService message with the MessageService */
      private log(message: string) {
        this.messageService.add(`HeroService: ${message}`);
      }
    }
```

Follow the error:

```
Argument type (error:any)=>Observable<Cart> is not assignable to parameter type (err:any, caught:Observable<T>)=> never
```

Comment: If there's a bug in the Angular docs, you should report that to them via GitHub. Do you have a *question*?

Comment: My question is how can I correct that error, it's a syntax typescript error documented, not a bug on Angular7. This is the reason that I am putting the question here, not in github. I am almost finding a solution here, if It works, I will put the answer in here

Comment: That's not a syntax error, it's a type error. You correct it by using the appropriate types. But if that erroneous example is in the official docs *that's a problem with the docs*.

Comment: And what is the appropriate types to use? This is the question, can you share?

Comment: It tells you that *in the error message*. It tells you what handleError currently returns, and what catchError is expecting.

Comment: i pasted the code into stackblitz. At least for typescript 3.11, angular 7.01 and rxjs6.6.3 there are no typeerrors. Which versions do you use?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"typescript": "~3.1.6"

Comment: @RogerGusmao I'm using `"@angular/cli": "~7.0.6", "rxjs": "~6.3.3", "typescript": "~3.1.6"` versions and I also cannot see any type errors.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out here, I really do not understand why you could not see the error too. But It was happening in here.

I changed the declaration of handleError, of parameters and to return a never type. Also I had to change the access fields of error object during the logging.

Follow the final code:

```
/** POST: add a new hero to the server */
  save(): Observable<Hero> {

    var o : Observable<Hero>=this.http.post<Hero>(
        "http://localhost/FoodMail/master/src/webservice.php?q=SalEBrasa", c, httpOptions)
        .pipe(
            tap((hero: Hero) => {this.log(`added hero w/ id=${hero.id}`)}),
            catchError<Hero>(this.handleError2.bind(this))
        );
    o.subscribe();
    return o;
  }
  private  handleError2<T>(error: any, caught: Observable<T>) : never{


    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error.message); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    this.log(`${error.statusText} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    //return of(err as T);
    throw  error;

  }
```